# If I move my printer to another site with a different internet connect with Google cloud print still work on it?

Tags: google-cloud-print

I've got a Google cloud print enabled printer (Epson WorkForce WF-7620DTWF) that I've setup to work with Google print.

I'm now going to move the printer to another location that will have a different internet connect (neither location has a static IP).

Will moving the printer to a new building with a different internet connect cause issues? Or does Google cloud print locate the printer by its MAC address or other identifying marker, rather than IP?

(I guess some people will suggest that this is off-topic, but I believe its on topic as its about how the Google cloud print app communicates with the actual printers.)

Comment: Why not just try it? Worst case is you need to re-set-up the printer.

Comment: @AlE. i would but i dont have the printer yet and the other site is an hours drive away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The printer is identified by Google Cloud Print with an ID that is unique per registration. If you un-register and re-register the printer, then you get a new ID. Cloud Print doesn't care about the printer's MAC address, or even it's IP address.

As long as the printer has an internet connection, it looks the same to Cloud Print and your users.